# Whats the best way to save an object with a list of the same object in firebase android

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a `Comment` object, which should contain child list of comments and each child list could contain a child list too. I am looking to save it to firebase database.

How do I structure it?

```
data class Comment constructor( val date : String,
                            val imageURL : String,
                            val text : String,
                            val author : String,
                            val id : String,
                            val children : List<Comment>)
```

Comment: Why do you need a list of `Comment` objects under a `Comment` object?

Comment: just to track child comments. Any better idea?

Answer (score 1):

In firebase name the parent node as Comment and child nodes same as the name of properties i.e date,imageUrl,text,author,id and children and child nodes of children are the list.

Comment: The problem is the list of comments. I would need to retrieve it and even update it when someone comments. And remember each of them in the list could just be like the parent class.

Answer (score 0):

The solution that worked was to save the children as `String` with their **ids** (keys).

```
data class Comment constructor( val date : String,
                            val imageURL : String,
                            val text : String,
                            val author : String,
                            val id : String,
                            val children : List<String>)
```